# how to animate stick arms

Tags: fireworks

I know this is a very basic question but I have kinda been thrown in at the deep end with this assignment for web development, I have managed to create 2 pretty good images on firewowkrs, but I have no idea how to animate them.I have had a little play around with the controls like the states and stuff and I still do not understand, i've tried the combined path and that doesnt seem to work for me. I would like to simply animate both of their arms to show that they are waving up and down. It consists of the stick arms and then the arms have four stick fingers as well, if this is of any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tutorial might help you grasp the basics of animation in firworks, it did for me

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/fireworks/articles/animated_logos.html

or you can have a read through some basics at the adobe website:

[Fireworks CS4 Basics](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Fireworks/10.0_Using/WS4c25cfbb1410b0021e63e3d1152b00d51f-7ffe.html)

or

[Fireworks CS5 Basics](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/fireworks/cs/using/WS4c25cfbb1410b0021e63e3d1152b00d51f-7ffe.html)

Hope this helps